# how to install JCE for JRE 8 on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: java, macos, jce

I want to install https://github.com/cryptomator/cli which requires:
JRE 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html
JCE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

On my Mac, Preferences > Java, Java tab, I see Platform 1.8, Product 1.8.0_121, and a path of 1.8   1.8.0_121   http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

So I think I have JRE 8 already. How do I tell if I have JCE, and how do I install it properly if it is not there?

Comment: You may want to [apple.se]

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy .jar files downloaded from here

```
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
```

and paste it into Java Home dictonary:

```
<java-home>/lib/security
```

In my case Java Home is here:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
```

Take note that **lib** folder should be inside **jre** folder cause **.../Home/** has **lib** folder too

Answer (score -3):

Here are the installation instructions:

1)  Download the unlimited strength JCE policy files.

2)  Uncompress and extract the downloaded file.

```
This will create a subdirectory called jce.
This directory contains the following files:

    README.txt                   This file
    local_policy.jar             Unlimited strength local policy file
    US_export_policy.jar         Unlimited strength US export policy file
```

3)  Install the unlimited strength policy JAR files.

```
In case you later decide to revert to the original "strong" but
limited policy versions, first make a copy of the original JCE
policy files (US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar). Then
replace the strong policy files with the unlimited strength
versions extracted in the previous step.

The standard place for JCE jurisdiction policy JAR files is:

    <java-home>/lib/security           [Unix]
    <java-home>\lib\security           [Windows]
```

It was apparently explained in the README.txt where you can get it after you downloaded the zip file(jce_policy-8.zip).

Comment: I am not sure that the instructions are appropriate for MacOS, as the installation instructions for Java are not the right way to deal with Java on a Mac so far as I know.

Comment: Mac Os is forked from linux kernel.Thats why Oracle never attempted to give separate instructions for it.So whats the issue here? you cant find jars in <java-home>/lib/security ?